# Integrating angularjs ui.map with geo location api

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, geocoding, google-geolocation

I am using 
http://jsfiddle.net/xSPAA/371/

```
//Add the requried module 'angular-ui' as a dependency
angular.module('maptesting', ['ui.map','ui.event']);

function MapCtrl($scope) {
    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(45, -73);
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: ll,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //Markers should be added after map is loaded
    $scope.onMapIdle = function() {
        if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.myMap,
                position: ll
            });
            $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
        }
    };

    $scope.markerClicked = function(m) {
        window.alert("clicked");
    };

}
```

plunker to show google map. I need to show a specific location map that a user will enter into a text box.

How can I do it?

Do I need to use Geo Location API?

Can any one give sample code or plunker?

Answer (score 3):

Below is the working example :

http://www.victorshi.com/blog/post/Use-Geolocation-API-with-Angularjs

[Example](http://victorshi.com/blog/examples/geolocation/geo.html)

Also check below url:

http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/11/05/some-geolocation-and-google-mapping-services-in-angularjs/

Google Location Service

http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/pEq6X/

```
directive 'googlePlaces'
```

Comment: http://www.victorshi.com/blog/post/Use-Geolocation-API-with-Angularjs page not found!